# I want my hosted blog to appear under a specific url

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have my webpage setup under example.com . Now, generally external hosted blog services like tumblr or posterous or wp would allow you to host your blog on your site i.e example.com. What I want instead is that my blog appear under example.com/b/ and so on. As I already have my webpage vhost configured for example.com. So how do I configure my apache sites?

Here is what I have for my existing apache vhost:

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /opt/example/

    <Directory /opt/example/>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes
        AddOutputFilter Includes html

        AddHandler mod_python .py
        PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
        PythonDebug Off
        DirectoryIndex index.py index.html
    </Directory>

    #Enable gzip for all content except images.
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
...
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This may depend on the blogging software you are using, but generally speaking, you could just put the blog installation under /opt/example/b.  Since /opt/example is the docroot for example.com, example.com/b would serve whatever was under the /b/ directory for that docroot.

You could also install the blog software in an entirely different location, and add the following to your config:

`Alias /b/ "/path/to/blog/installation"`

Then when someone hits example.com/b, they will be served the content from /path/to/blog/installation